# Using a matrix to organise values into groups

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have a matrix of size 6 x 6.

Six students are 'ranking' six other students (including themselves). If I wanted to organise them into let's say, groups of three without picking and choosing the 'best' matches, how would I do so?

Thanks in advance :)

More information added:

A population of n students are asked to provide preferences on who they would like to be grouped with. To do so student's provide numerical ratings on their fellow class mates. The scale can be positive, negative, both positive and negative, contain zero, whole numbers, decimals, etc. (You get to choose the scale).

From this, I am to make a way to create student groupings. For instance, each student would provide n sets of data. The resulting matrix would be n x n in dimension. Hopefully I shall be able to apply the resulting formula/steps to different group sizes.

I think a scale for the students to use from 1-5 distributes the preferences easily. A scale from 1-5 distributes the ‘feelings’ evenly. (1, extreme dislike. 2, dislike. 3, Neutral. 4, Like. 5, Extreme like.)

I have also decided that you don’t have to have the students give their feelings on EVERY other student (would take forever). It can be assumed that the students they don’t comment about are the neutral value for the scale.

What I have currently done is set up the student's ranking in a matrix defined as A.

Therefore the transpose of A (A') will have student two's ranking in the same spot, etc.

Therefore A + A'  shall equal the student's overall compatibility rating.

From there you can pick out the maximum values, match them up and create groups.

What this solution's problems is, is that it is very time-consuming for a larger group (~150 students) and that the first students separated into groups have a better likelihood of getting into a group with their preferred partners than the last few students.

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.  Can you specify more?

Comment: I just added more information to the original post. Hope I explained it better! I also added what I have come up with currently.